# Find the biggest difference in multiple dates using a loop Java

Tags: java

Im trying to find the biggest difference between several dates how would that be possible? The answer to this should be 01012001-01012011. I'm trying to find the biggest date gap between two lists how would that be possible?

```
public void Date (){
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    List<String> start = Arrays.asList("01011992","01012001","01012001");
    String dateBeforeString = start.get(2);  
    List<String> end = Arrays.asList("02012001","02012001","01012011");
    String dateAfterString = end.get(2);

    try {        
        Date dateBefore = myFormat.parse(dateBeforeString);
        Date dateAfter = myFormat.parse(dateAfterString);
        long difference = dateAfter.getTime() - dateBefore.getTime();
        daysBetween = (difference / (1000*60*60*24));

        System.out.println("Days: "+daysBetween);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: Could you be more clear on your question

Comment: @CertainPerformance And hamster is to hampster as spelling is to spellping

Comment: Please define "biggest difference between several dates".

Comment: @Haem The answer should be 01012001-01012011 that is the biggest difference in between the dates. Im trying to find out which of these dates in the list has the biggest date gap. So by comparing two lists you should get the result but how?

Comment: Hi, and what is the error which you are getting, where is the mentioned loop, which are you using? 
Welcome to stackoverflow, we are not there to help you solve the homeworks, start at [mcve] then feel free to edit the post. Simple advise- you have to iterate over arraylists and compare values, in this case you will need to have loop in the loop , for hint look eg. [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943663/how-to-iterate-through-an-arraylist-of-objects-of-arraylist-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
 SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
        List<String> start = Arrays.asList("01011992", "01012001", "01012001");
        List<String> end = Arrays.asList("02012001", "02012001", "01012011");



        int lastIndex =0;
        long lastValue =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < start.size(); i++) {
            String dateBeforeString = start.get(i);
            String dateAfterString = end.get(i);
            try {
                Date dateBefore = myFormat.parse(dateBeforeString);
                Date dateAfter = myFormat.parse(dateAfterString);
                long difference = dateAfter.getTime() - dateBefore.getTime();
                long daysBetween = (difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));


                if(lastValue<daysBetween){
                    lastValue=daysBetween;
                    lastIndex = i;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("result: " +  start.get(lastIndex)+"-"+end.get(lastIndex)+" maxDiff "+lastValue);
```

Comment: Looks like works, but so complicated to the new members, if he is asking to how write loop, I dont think so, he will knowns the streams.
He was asking for loop, there is none

Comment: @Nonika Even though this works it doesn't do what I want. In yours it compares the whole string with the other and finds the biggest difference the whole string.

Comment: So you need pair from these lists where difference is max and index is same?

Comment: @Nonika I want to compare both lists. So for example the first index in the first and second string should compare in between each other. It cannot be first index from list start and second index from list end. In this situation indexes two have the biggest day difference.Do you understand?

Comment: so element at index i in list 'start' compared to element at index i from list 'end'?

Comment: if so check last example